# How to correctly implement DI using EF (DB first)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to implement DI (using Ninject if it does matter)in my project. For now i have `QuestionController`,which is using `QuestionRepository`:

```
    private readonly IQuestionRepository _questionRepository;

    public QuestionsController(IQuestionRepository questionRepository)
    {
        _questionRepository = questionRepository;
    }
```

This is ok,but my `QuestionRepository` needs `AskEntities` object,where `AskEntities` is class generated by EF designer. So now in `QuestionRepository` i have   :

```
 private AskEntities Db;
```

How to implement there not class but interface (someting like `IAskEntities`) ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is unclear what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

> but my QuestionRepository needs AskEntities object,where AskEntities is class generated by EF designer. So now in QuestionRepository i have `private AskEntities Db;` How to implement there not class but interface (someting like IAskEntities) ?

Well. I assume that your AskEntities object is your `DbContext`? Since your repository implementation is specific to Entity Framework I see no reason to abstract away that dependency from your repository class.

You could of course send in `DbContext` base class and use `context.Set<Question>` to access different sets. But what advantage would that give you? You typically only write integration tests for repository classes, hence no need to create another abstraction.